# wxStaticText inconsistently displays 'degree' character

Tags: wxwidgets

In the same application I have two different instances of wxStaticText. Each displays an angular value expressed in degrees. I've tested both instances for font name and font encoding. They are the same for both. I've tested that both strings passed to SetLabel() are using the same character value, decimal 176. Yet one displays the 'degree' character (small circle, up high) as expected and the other instead displays an odd character I'm not familiar with. How can this be? Is there some other property of wxStaticText I need to test?

Comment: I think we need more info. I'd look at platform, wx version (things have changed from 2.8 to 3.0), all character encodings involved, binary contents of both strings.

Answer (score 0):

I can't explain what you're seeing because obviously two identical controls must behave in the same way, but I can tell you that using decimal 176 is not a good way to encode the degree sign, unless you explicitly use `wxConvISO8859_1` to create the corresponding `wxString`.

It is better to use `wxString::FromUTF8("\xc2\xb0")` instead or, preferably, make sure that your source files are UTF-8 encoded and just use `wxString::FromUTF8("°")`.

Comment: Thanks, makes no difference with my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Arghhhh! Found it. I was assuming SetLabel() was wxStaticText::SetLabel(), inherited from the wxWindow base class. It's not. We have a wrapper class of our own around wxStaticText that I was not aware of. It's the wrapper class that is bollixing the string value.

Moral: When debugging unfamiliar code, don't make assumptions, step ALL THE WAY in.